# C# unassigned variable?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am new to C# programming, and I don't know very much of its syntax or how it works, but I've been learning and it's  been coming along quite nicely.  I'm trying to convert one of my programs I have recently written in Python to C# so it can run on windows without having to install Python.  And I've had to change a lot of my methods in converting it, and it's taken a very long time to do, but I've been figuring most things out as I go along.  This issue, however, makes absolutely no sense to me.  I have assigned a value and a type to the double 'b1' but it's telling me that I can't use it in the definition of b2?

```
            double b;
            double b1;
            double b2;
            if (noSlope == true)
                b = 0;
            else
                b1 = slopem * Convert.ToDouble(x1);
                b2 = Convert.ToDouble(y1) - b1;
                b = b2;
```

Visual Studio has been telling me that 'b1' is an unassigned local variable.  I thought I just assigned it on the line above?  Can anyone tell me why it is doing this, or how to assign a value to b1 so it can be used?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your main problem is a lack of `{}` after the `else`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In c# blocks are marked using `{` and `}`, not indentation. Your current code is equivalent to

```
double b;
double b1;
double b2;
if (noSlope == true)
{
    b = 0;
}
else
{
    b1 = slopem * Convert.ToDouble(x1);
}
b2 = Convert.ToDouble(y1) - b1;
b = b2;
```

As you can see, when the condition is evaluated to `true` you will not have `b1` assigned.

PS. You can rewrite your code to

```
double b;
if (noSlope == true)
{
    b = 0;
}
else
{
    b = Convert.ToDouble(y1) - slopem * Convert.ToDouble(x1);
}
```

or even

```
double b = noSlope ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(y1) - slopem * Convert.ToDouble(x1);
```